# Power automate Approval Flow question - Can you update the "Status" column in Teams based on a field value?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, powerapps-forms, approval, status

I have an Approval flow (Create and Approval, and Wait for an Approval).  When an approval response is given in in the Teams/Email notification, it updates the "Status" column in the "Activity" tab in Teams. Is there a way I can update that column without an approval response in Teams/Email?  My requirement is tricky...have an Approval flow with quick/easy responses in teams/email, but also give them the ability to navigate to the PowerApps form to provide a response there.  When they do that, the Approval flow's Status remains as "Requested".

Thanks!